# jquery get dynamic span id value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I have added facebook SDK in my web project, and i am printing all the values through id but i have one doubt.How to get the dynamic id value through jquery or javascript.

**My Code**

```
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);      
    var fullname = document.getElementById('admin_name').innerHTML = response.name;
});
```

//Displaying through html

`<span id="admin_name"></span>` and it's printing successfully.

But when i wants to get the id value through jquery or javascript it's coming null or empty.

//Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var adminName = $("#admin_name").text();
   alert(adminName);
});
```

**My Complete Login As Facebook Code**

```
function statusChangeCallback(response) 
{
   console.log(response);   
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
  } 
}
function checkLoginState() {
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
   statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
}
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {FB.init({
 appId      : '12345678910',
 cookie     : true,  
 xfbml      : true,  
 version    : 'v2.2' 
});
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
};
// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) 
       return;
       js = d.createElement(s); 
       js.id = id;
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
function testAPI() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      var fullname = document.getElementById('admin_name').innerHTML = response.name;
    });
}
```

**And Calling through FB Login Button**

```
<fb:login-button max_rows="1" 
    size="large" 
    show_faces="false" 
    auto_logout_link="false"  
    onlogin="checkLoginState();">Login with Facebook
</fb:login-button>
```

Comment: That's because you're *getting* the value before calling the `FB.api` function that *sets* the initial value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is one of timing. The dom is going to grab what value is currently there, not one that will be there soon. At the time `$(document).ready` is called, your `FB.api` has not. Therefore, it will return null. Call the function *after* your FB.api is called.

Programmatically:

Stick your `alert` code in a function

```
alertMe = function(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
       var adminName = $("#admin_name").text();
       alert(adminName);
    });
}
```

and call that function when your FB API is done doing its thing

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);      
    var fullname = document.getElementById('admin_name').innerHTML = response.name;
    alertMe(); //send the call for the alert
});
```

Comment: @AnshumanPattnaik where is your FB.api code executed? As an on click for an element? Or an onload for a FB plugin element?